# Get the max value corresponding to primary key combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
Key1   Key2    Take  Value    Value2   Value3
K11    K21     Yes     1000     10       5   #Include: Take is Yes, Value column is positive
K11    K21     Yes    -1000     10       5  #Remove:Value column is negative
K13    K23     Yes     2000     20       2   #Include:Take is Yes, Value positive
K13    K23     Yes    -2000     20       2  #Remove:Value is negative
K41    K44     No      4000     100      590  #Remove: Take is No
K41    K44     No     -4000     100      590  #Remove:Value negative, Take NO
```

Now for example for the same keys K11,K21 combination we have 2 values one negative one positive. How to take only the positive value from this df. Note that Value2 and Value3 columns have same values for positive and negative values of Value column. Also the `Take` column should be Yes for the row to be considered

Expected output

```
 Key1   Key2   Take       Value     Value2   Value3
 K11    K21     Yes       1000      10       5
 K13    K23     Yes       2000     20       2
```

Note that for my df both keys together are primary key (the combination of Key1,Key2 has to be unique).

```
  df_trial=(df['Take']=='Yes).groupby(['Key1','Key2'], as_index=False).max('Value')
```

This is not working . I am getting typeerror `TypeError: as_index=False only valid with DataFrame`

Comment: Good point, editted now..Value column is actually integer. had taken dummy data

Comment: This works : ``df.loc[df.Take.eq("Yes") & (np.sign(df.Value) >= 0)]`` However, you may want to add more rows for better tests, for scenarios where there are multiple yeses and positive values

Comment: I want to take the max value out of positive values. Will this code return max positive value?